# I need a packet-level explanation of how HTTP redirects to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, tcp

I am programming an embedded web server and trying to figure out how to redirect all incoming SYN packets on port 80 to redirect to port 443. Everything I've found online is in the context of Apache, NGIX, etc, and none of that applies to what I'm working with.

Edit:

Here is what I understand of the process so far:

1. The browser initiates the TCP 3-way handshake on port 80, let's assume it is successful.
2. Upon receiving the first HTTP GET request, the server should return a `301 Moved Permanently` (or `308 Permanent Redirect`?) back to the browser.
3. The browser should then initiate the TLS handshake on port 443

FWIW, this is a LAN device with no Internet access.

Comment: You'll probably need to have a closer look at the HTTP protocol and how to send a [location header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location). Item #1 in your post involves opening a socket connection. Step 2 would be to write `Location: https://example.com` (followed by appropriate newline chars) to the socket. To complete your response, I think you'd need two newline chars or something. I expect HTTPS 'handshaking' is non-trivial, and will require some effort. A packet dump with wireshark might be very instructive.

Comment: "edirect all incoming SYN packets" - You probably need to take a closer look at the TCP protocol and how streams are negotiated. And UNDERSTAND the difference between packets and streams. HTTP uses datagrams ON TOP of streams. It knows NOTHING about packets. While its technically possible to embed data exchange within the initial handshake, this is not going to work with an off-the-shelf client.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. The browser initiates the TCP 3-way handshake on port 80, let's assume it is successful.

correct.

> 2. Upon receiving the first HTTP GET request, the server should return a 301 Moved Permanently (or 308 Permanent Redirect?) back to the browser.

Usually a 301. This is sufficient for a GET request. The actual packets on the wire here do not matter: TCP is about a byte stream and how this byte stream is packetized is irrelevant for the functionality.

> 3. The browser should then initiate the TLS handshake on port 443

Before the browser can do the TLS handshake on port 443 it has to create a TCP connection on port 443, similar to what it did in step 1 with port 80.

And again, the actual packetizing of the TLS handshake does not matter since TCP is about a byte stream. For how the TLS handshake works in terms of transferred data see for example [What happens in a TLS handshake? | SSL handshake](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/).

After the TLS handshake was completed the browser is sending the GET request, but over the TLS connection and thus encrypted.

Comment: More simply, after it gets the redirect, it just starts over as if the original URL had been the URL in the `Location:` header.

Comment: To make things absolutely clear, you might add that after receiving the 301 reply, the browser *closes* the connection to port 80 and opens a *new* connection to port 443.

Answer (score 1):

> I am programming an embedded web server and trying to figure out how to redirect all incoming SYN packets on port 80 to redirect to port 443. Everything I've found online is in the context of Apache, NGIX, etc, and none of that applies to what I'm working with.

These are two different layers on the network stack: SYN packets are part of TCP handshake, which is used to form a bidirectional communication channel between client and web server. Over this TCP connection, HTTP protocol is used to make requests and send responses back.

Without closer context it is difficult to know if you are using an existing TCP stack, or are you also implementing TCP.

If you are using an existing TCP stack, I would recommend to use Libevent to work as an HTTP server. An example is at: https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/sample/http-server.c

Then, you can add a little logic to handle the request / response logic you want.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to install a small nginx webserver and make network capture with a tool like whireshark and make a few captures to see what happens.